# Vim replace pattern with specific condition

Tags: regex, vim

I need to replace `;\s*\<do\>` with `\rdo` in Vim. However, I also need to make sure `;\s*\<do\>` does not get replaced if there is a Fortran comment symbol `!` before it, i.e., in the search patter `!.*;\s*\<do\>`. For example, `; do` in the uncommented line

```
j=2; do i=1, 10
```

should be replaced as

```
j=2
do i=1,10
```

But `; do` in the following commented part should not be replaced,

```
 k=3 ! j=2; do i=1, 10
```

How can I do this in vim ? I tried `\(!.*\)\@!;\s*\<do\>` and it does not work.

Comment: Can you post an example input file and the expected output?

Comment: I don't think you should ask this question here, superuser may be a better place

Comment: There is also https://vi.stackexchange.com/ but vi(m) questions have always been accepted on SO...

Comment: The question has been updated with an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I edited this answer based on your example:

Try using `:g!/<pattern1>/s/<pattern2>/<replacement>/g`:

```
:g!/!.*/s/\v;\s*do/\rdo/g
```

This does the replacement of `pattern2` with `replacement` only on lines that don't contain `pattern1`.

*Original answer:*

The following pattern should do what you requested: `/[^*]\{0,1\}\zs;\\s\*\\<do\\>`.
You can use it to replace it with whatever you want, e.g. `%s/<pattern>/\rdo/g`.

Comment: note the leading `/` is the search command, not part of the actual regex.

Comment: This does not work. Maybe I do not  phrase my question properly. By `!.*;\s*\<do\>`, I mean a search pattern. See the updated question.

Comment: sorry, before you added an example it seemed like you were trying to replace literal search patterns.

Comment: Finally I figured out an alternative way to do the match, `\c\(!.*\)\@<!;\s*\<do\>`

Answer (score 0):

```
:v/!/ s/; /\r/g

:v  .......... global negation (all lines without pattern)
/!/ .......... all lines not containing !
s ............ substitution
; ............ semicolon space
\r ........... Carriage return "Enter"
```